# Android activity instance in memory even after destroying the activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Eclipse MAT  histogram shows SplashActivity  instance exists even after launching MemTweaksActivity.Do anybody have any idea about this.

public class SplashActivity extends Activity{

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MemTweaksActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();

                }
            },2000);

}
```

}

But the following code with out any timer successfully removed the SplashActivity instance. MAT shows 0 instance of SplashActivity .

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MemTweaksActivity.class);       startActivity(i); finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add logging for the lifecycle calls `onPause()`, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` in your SplashActivity. You will see that these get called at some point before/after MemTweaksActivity is run. The garbage collector will remove the SpashScreen activity from memory when it feels the need to. You can't force this to happen.

**EDIT:**

The reason that SplashScreenActivity is still there is because you've not cleaned up the Timer.

Do this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MemTweaksActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            // Release timer resources
            timer.cancel();         
        }
    },2000);
}
```

Comment: OK. That would imply that the TimerTask instance is still in memory and it has a reference to SplashScreenActivity. You could do a heap dump and see what object is holding a reference to SplashScreenActivity. It may also be that the garbage collector needs to make a few passes before it removes SplashScreenActivity due to the other references to it.

Comment: I edited my answer. You need to cleanup the timer's resources

Comment: Timer task instance is not in memory. Instead of timer task even if i use Android handler to postdelay the code for 2sec got same output.Code is very simple but dono why even calling finish and ondestroy callback fired activity still in stack.

Comment: The activity isn't still in the stack. If onDestroy() is called then the activity is dead. Just because it is in memory doesn't mean anything. The garbage collector will probably get around to cleaning it up. Have you checked the heap dump to see what object has a reference to it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14854/discussion-between-newentry-and-david-wasser)